# Question about an inhibition process spatstat

Tags: statistics, gis, spatial, spatstat

I am working with a data set of a pattern of spatial points that present an inhibition process but caused by angles, that is, they repel each other according to a given angle (azimuth of 0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270 and 315) and not by distance, my question is the following:

1. is there a K, L and G function based on angles? or do you recommend any other technique?
2. is there any spatial point pattern process that is not inhibited by distances but by angles?

Best regards

Jesús Andrades

I am trying to solve a problem based on angles, the events present a spatial repulsion process but based on angles.